# Is it possible to make several jquery plugins to share the same variable?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I asked a question how to get another plugin's variable before , but I thought it was not the right way to resolve my problem.So,I think the best way maybe to share the same variable.
E.g:

I have a **global variable zIndex** , and each time my **plugin** [ may be plugin1,plugin2...] create a new element it gets the **z-index** value from it and plus one and assign back to **zIndex** , and every time the element which was click, the element get the latest **zIndex** value and plus one and return it to **zIndex**.

So,every new created **elements** could get the **latest zIndex value**,and every time the **element** was **clicked**,it get the **latest zIndex** and **update the zIndex value.**

**and the question is: Is it possible to share this kind of global variable among plugins and how could I update the global variable inside the plugin??**

**Thank you very much!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have full control over your plugins, you can just use a simple **Closure** to share variables:

```
(function($) {
     var mySharedVariable = "shared";

     $.extend($.fn, {
         plugin1:  function() {
            return this.each(function(i,e) {
                mySharedVariable = "plugin1";
            });
         },
         plugin2:  function() {
            return this.each(function(i,e) {
                mySharedVariable = "plugin2";
            });
         }
     });
}(jQuery));
```

Since the functions **plugin1** and **plugin2** have the same **parent scope** (or more precisely, their Activation-Object), they will share the access to `mySharedVariable`.

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/EMpQN/

Comment: Good answer, though you need to work on bolding some of that text.

Comment: I am new to create jquery plugin.So, it is a little difficult to follow what you suggestion.I'll try it tomorrow ,and it will be good for me if you can give me an example or more explanation to show how to get and set the variable in your way! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @qinHaiXiang: example link added :)